# Determine if mapped points are related geographically

Tags: r, ggmap

Hoping you can help. I'm a clinician trying to determine if some mapped points are related.
I basically have a data set of certain long/latitudes.
Each lat/long is associated with a positive Sputum Culture for a certain bacteria. Say pathogen A.
I have another 'control' dataset with Sputum cultures of a more predominant normal pathogen with associated lat longs. Pathogen B.

Is there an easy way to determine if there's a geographic relation to these points. For example, if you live in this geographical area are you more likely to get said pathogen.

I have plotted the points in R using ggmap and was hoping to visually determine a link, however there's a lot of noise.

Can somebody guide me to where I can learn how to go about doing this. 
Happy to try to figure this out on my own, just not sure where to start.

Comment: If you could edit this post to provide details of the points and what they mean and describe the sense of "related," then you would have a much better chance of getting appropriate replies.

Comment: Done, hope this is adequate. Sorry very new to this.

Comment: I would suggest you read about spatial correlation, Moran's I, Geary's C and similar statistics to start. It is a fair question, but too broad as it stands.

Comment: Much appreciated. Will get started with this!

Comment: Have you made any progress? Could you edit to show what you've tried, and perhaps share some sample data? Interesting question!